# In Ravendb track request count per session

Tags: ravendb

Is there a way to get the request count per session in RavenDB so as to use it for optimization? Like reducing the calls made etc. I know RavenDB limits it to 30 per session. What I would like to know is the count of requests made at any given time. (In code, during run time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the number of requests for a session use `session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests`.

Comment: Thanks. It would have been nicer if there were events associated with the changes.

Comment: What do you mean by events and changes? `session.Advanced` may give you more insights: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/how-to/check-if-there-are-any-changes-on-a-session

Comment: I mean events like BeforeSessionRequest / AfterSessionRequest etc. These would really help in understanding what happens inside a session.

Comment: You can setup profiling in RavenDB. On your documentStore instance there's a method `InitializeProfiling()`. You can then get the profiling info `var profilingInformation = session.Advanced.DocumentStore.GetProfilingInformationFor(((DocumentSession)session).Id); profilingInformation.DumpToLog();`